# Django show error in form that comes from another function

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to post a ModelForm, but after the is_valid() function, I run another validation coming from another function.

What I want to do is, if the result of the other function is false, the form should raise an error, above the form as in the case "your password cannot be the same".

Since the function runs during the process, I cannot use a clean method in model.

Thanks in advance!

function

```py
def somefunction():
.
.
    print ("NOT WORKING")
    return False
```

views.py

```py
def index(request):
    form = SomeForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            if somefunction() == True:
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/contact/")
            else:
                form
        else: 
            form
    return render(request, "home.html", {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `add_error` method to add error to form manually like this.

```
form.add_error('<FIELD_NAME>)', 'your password cannot be the same')
```

But I suggest you to override [clean method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.clean) of `form` instead.